# get class Name + Inheritance

Tags: c++

How I will be able to get the class name father of the diagram?.

```
Father *a = new Father();
a = &(FatherFactory::getCode("Goppa")); //getcode return a type Nieto 
Grandfather *c3 = a;
```

I trying using typeid method but I get the grandfather class name i.e typeid(c3).name(); and if I write typeid(*c3).name() I get the Nieto class name. But I want get the Father class name ...

```
Father & FatherFactory::getCode(char* codeName)
{

   return *(new Nieto());

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you realize you're leaking memory when you reassign `a`?

Comment: @David I edit question getCode method return a type Nieto but casting with Father class. Equal you think that I leaking memory?

Comment: It is simply irrational.  Simply look at c3: It is a pointer to Grandfather, pointing at an instance of Nieto.  By what rationale you think we can get "Father" through c3?  Parent class of the class of the actual instance? or what?...

Comment: @Juan It is obviously you don't get the point raised by David :P  It is still leaking memory after you edit your code :P

Comment: but 'a' have a Father type too ...

Comment: You have your inherence hierarchy inverted also... For example you have a father is always a grandfather...

Comment: @Juan That's why I said: simply look at c3.  Once assignment to c3 is done, c3 have nothing to do with the original variable.  Do you expect the compiler to "trace" which variable c3 is assigned with and what's the type of that original variable? it is simply irrational.  Maybe give us some actual reason why you want to do it.  I believe it is simply some design thought issue

Answer (score 0):

if you need name of immediate base, you will have to add virtual function returning it and carefully implement it in every class. but it is not clear what do you want and why and you still leak object from first line on second. your question is strange, probably you have to learn c++ better